# Attack enemy in front of character

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have auto attacking system where i am attacking enemies within range. Problem is i do not want to attack enemies behind me but only in front so i used `Physics.Raycast` and it is working fine when there is 1 enemy inside my collider trigger but when there are more (let's say 2 of them), and one enemy is behind and one in front, first i check raycast and it is returning true, but since enemy behind me enter collider first, my spell is casting to it's location. So how can i cast spell (get position) of object that is in front of me?

Here is code i am casting spell with:

```
public void castSpell(GameObject caster, GameObject other, float duration)
{
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    if(castOnlyForward && !Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10))
    {
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log("ON");    
    if(animationEnabled)
    {
        foreach(var a in animator)
        {
            foreach(var b in a.bools)
            {
                a.animator.SetBool(b.parameterName, b.parameterValue);
            }
            foreach(var i in a.ints)
            {
                a.animator.SetInteger(i.parameterName, i.parameterValue);
            }
            foreach(var f in a.floats)
            {
                a.animator.SetFloat(f.parameterName, f.parameterValue);
            }
        }
    }

    GameObject Temporary_Spell_Handler;
    Temporary_Spell_Handler = Instantiate(_Spell, Spell_Emitter.transform.position, Spell_Emitter.transform.rotation) as GameObject;


    //Add Spell Script to the casted spell so it handes damage and everything about spells.
    Spell tempSpell = Temporary_Spell_Handler.GetComponent<Spell>();
    tempSpell.caster = caster;

    if(b_lenghtScale)
    {
        float percent = currentDistance / (maxDistance / 100);
        ParticleSystemRenderer pr = Temporary_Spell_Handler.GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
        pr.lengthScale = -(((lenghtScale - Math.Abs(pr.lengthScale)) / 100) * percent);
        Vector3 newScale = new Vector3();
        newScale.x = (maxScale.x / 100) * percent;
        newScale.y = (maxScale.y / 100) * percent;
        newScale.z = (maxScale.z / 100) * percent;

        Temporary_Spell_Handler.transform.localScale = newScale;
    }

    if(lookAtEnemy)
    {
        if(other.transform.parent != null && other.transform.parent.gameObject.tag == "pivotChange")
        {
            Temporary_Spell_Handler.transform.LookAt(other.transform.parent.gameObject.transform);
        }
        else
        {
            Temporary_Spell_Handler.transform.LookAt(other.transform);
        }
    }

    Destroy(Temporary_Spell_Handler, duration);
}
```

And here i cast `castSpell`:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if(caster.tag == "Player")
    {
        if(CharacterCommands.autoAttacking)
        {
            if(enemiesTags.Contains(col.tag))
            {
                if(!paused)
                {
                    currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(caster.transform.position, col.transform.position);
                    StartCoroutine(Repeat(castSpellEveryNSeconds, () => { castSpell(caster, col.gameObject, spellDuration); }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(frequentlyCastSpell)
        {
            if(enemiesTags.Contains(col.tag))
            {
                if(!paused)
                {
                    currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(caster.transform.position, col.transform.position);
                    StartCoroutine(Repeat(castSpellEveryNSeconds, () => { castSpell(caster, col.gameObject, spellDuration); }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need anything else please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis:**

OnTriggerStay is called multiple times per frame, if there are multiple colliders inside.

Your code then starts 2 Coroutines that call

```
castSpell(caster, ...
```

So since caster is the same in both cases, the 2nd coroutine call will probably overwrite the first, and therefore always casting the spell at one of them, not both.

**My Suggestion:**

You fake some field-of-view system. Before you start the Coroutine, you check the [Vector3.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) from `player.transform.forward` against die Vector, that connects player and enemy position. That is, simply the difference: `player.transform.position - enemy.transform.position` - or in your case, `collider.transform.position` for the enemy.

You may need to switch the operands in the substraction, cannot test right now.

**Code from my brain:**

```
float angle = Vector3.Angle(player.transform.forward, player.transform.positon - collider.transform.position);
Debug.Log("the angle is: " + angle);
if(angle > -45 && angle < 45){
    // start your spell casting coroutine here
}
```

Make sure do read the console when testing this, I am not 100%  sure how the angle values will come out. Especially around 0.

Comment: It is working. Just to mention you (edit answer), only angle i needed to put is `angle > 90` because in documentation it says `The angle returned is always the non reflex angle between the two vectors - ie the smaller of the two possible angles between them and never greater than 180 degrees.`

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is calculate the Dot product as explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html). This is a more solid solution, rather than using angles which may result in odd behavior.

Comment: I can help if you share code. You will likely encountering other problems by using the other method as mentioned here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Comment: The part where you tried to calculate the dot product in order to determine if something's behind/in front of you